# How do I sort a structure array with multiple conditions?

Tags: c, sorting

In this case, I got a struct as below:

```
struct student_list{
    int id;
    char *name[50];
    char department[100];
    char program[100];
    float cgpa;
}studlist[5];
```

How do I sort the list by indicates both alphabetical ordering of names, ascending order of Id Number and alphabetical ordering of department names?

Below are what I've been done, but it turns out error:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct student_list{
    int id;
    char name[50];
    char department[100];
    char program[100];
    float cgpa;
}studlist[5];

int comp(const void *a, const void *b){
    int result;
    const char **str_a=(const char **)a;
    const char **str_b=(const char **)b;
    return strcmp(*str_a, *str_b);
}

main(){
    int num, i, j;
    char *temp;
    
    printf("Number of student?:");
    scanf(" %d", &num);
    
    printf("\n-----------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\nPlease enter all information in capital letter!!\n");
    
    for(i=0; i<num; i++){
        printf("\nStudent %d", i+1);
        printf("\nEnter student ID:");
        scanf(" %d", &studlist[i].id);
        printf("\nEnter student name:");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", &studlist[i].name);
        printf("\nEnter student department:");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", &studlist[i].department);
        printf("\nEnter student program:");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", &studlist[i].program);
        printf("\nEnter student cgpa:");
        scanf(" %f", &studlist[i].cgpa);
    }
    
    qsort(studlist.name, num, sizeof(char*), comp);
    
    printf("\n------------------Student Information----------------------");
    printf("\nID\t\tName\t\tDepartment\t\tProgram\t\t\tCGPA");
    for(i=0; i<num; i++){
        printf("\n%d\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t\t%.2f", studlist[i].id, studlist[i].name, studlist[i].department, studlist[i].program, studlist[i].cgpa);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

After applying the changes suggested in the answers, I now have the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct student_list{
    int id;
    char name[50];
    char department[100];
    char program[100];
    float cgpa;
}studlist[5];

int comp(const void *a, const void *b);

int comp(const void *a, const void *b){
    int result;
    struct student_list* stud_a;
    struct student_list* stud_b;
    
    stud_a=(struct student_list*)a;
    stud_b=(struct student_list*)b;
    
    result=strcmp(stud_a->name, stud_a->name);
    if(result!=0){
        return result;
    }   
    
    result=strcmp(stud_a->id, stud_a->id);
    if(result!=0){
        return result;
    }   
    
    result=strcmp(stud_a->department, stud_a->department);
    if(result!=0){
        return result;
    }   
}

main(){
    int num, i, j;
    
    printf("Number of student?:");
    scanf(" %d", &num);
    
    printf("\n-----------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\nPlease enter all information in capital letter!!\n");
    
    for(i=0; i<num; i++){
        printf("\nStudent %d", i+1);
        printf("\nEnter student ID:");
        scanf(" %d", &studlist[i].id);
        printf("\nEnter student name:");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", &studlist[i].name);
        printf("\nEnter student department:");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", &studlist[i].department);
        printf("\nEnter student program:");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", &studlist[i].program);
        printf("\nEnter student cgpa:");
        scanf(" %f", &studlist[i].cgpa);
    }
    
    qsort(studlist, num, sizeof(struct student_list), comp);
    
    printf("\n------------------Student Information----------------------");
    printf("\nID\t\tName\t\tDepartment\t\tProgram\t\t\tCGPA");
    for(i=0; i<num; i++){
        printf("\n%d\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t\t%.2f", studlist[i].id, studlist[i].name, studlist[i].department, studlist[i].program, studlist[i].cgpa);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I cannot link the `int comp(const void *a, const void *b);` to my `qsort()` in my main function, and another problem is I cannot compare string and integer at the same `int comp(const void *a, const void *b);`

Comment: Write a comparision function that satisfies your condition and use [`qsort()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort). [`strcmp()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) is useful for comparing strings.

Comment: But when I tried to use this two, it comes out error in my code, is it possible for you to show me an example?

Comment: @Prof Show us what you tried so we can help you find the error.

Comment: I updated in my question, can you help me to see where is my error?

Comment: Pass the entire array to the sort function: `qsort(studlist, num, sizeof(struct student_list), comp);` Then in the compare function, cast the pointers to `student_list *`.

Comment: It doesn't let me pass to student_list*

Comment: Post the **exact** error message from your compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't compile:

```
qsort(studlist.name, num, sizeof(char*), comp);
```

Because `studlist` is an array of structs, not a single struct, and therefore doesn't have members.

It seems your intent based on this and the comparison function was to sort by name, but this isn't how you do it.  The `qsort` function takes your array as the first parameter and the size of the array element as the third.  So you would call it like this:

```
qsort(studlist, num, sizeof(struct student_list), comp);
```

Then the parameters to the comparison function would be pointers to the struct type:

```
int comp(const void *a, const void *b){
    const struct student_list *student_a = a;
    const struct student_list *student_b = b;
    return strcmp(student_a->name, student_b->name);
}
```

Now with access to the full struct in the comparison function, you can do additional check if `strcmp` returns 0 based on the other fields.

Regarding this in your updated code:

```
result=strcmp(stud_a->id, stud_a->id);
```

The `strcmp` function is used to compare strings but the `id` field has type `int`.  So you would instead do something like this:

```
if (stud_a->id < stud_b->id) {
    result = -1;
} else if (stud_a->id > stud_b->id) {
    result = 1;
} else {
    result = 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your way, which come out this code:
int comp(const void *a, const void *b){
 const struct student_list *stud_a = a;
 const struct student_list *stud_b = b;
 return strcmp(stud_a->name, stud_b->name);
}
It still error, it doesn't let me to pass const void* to const student_list*

Comment: @Prof Casts to/from `void *` without a cast are allowed in C.  Are you using a C++ compiler?

Comment: Yess, I'm using Dev C++ to do this, is it why I can't compile?

Comment: I finally solved the problem just now, but it comes out another problem. I can pass const void to const student_list* now, but for int I still can't pass. And how do I call qsort() in my main function?

Comment: I got it!! Is finally work!! Thank you so much for your helping!!

Comment: @Prof Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison function can be something like this:

```
int cmp_student_lists(const void *_A, const void *_B){
    int res;
    struct student_list* A;
    struct student_list* B;

    A = (struct student_list*) _A;
    B = (struct student_list*) _B;

    res = strcmp(A->name, B->name);
    if(res != 0){
        return res;
    }

    res = ...;
    if(res != 0){
        return res;
    }
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

You can add as many subcomparisons as you like, however, you need to invent the order yourself.

Comment: I tried you way, it also error that I can't pass const void* to const student_list*